# Is Slovio effective as an international language?

Tags: russian, slavic

I know that Slovio is not very popular but if I write or speak in this language, will I be understood by Russian or Ukrainian as their website says?
If someone has experience to share, it helps me to decide if I should learn this conlang.

http://www.slovio.com/

Comment: See also https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/784/is-there-any-evidence-that-learning-a-zonal-slavic-conlang-can-help-conversing-w (unfortunately, still without an answer)